# Get Layer using GeoServer and OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers

I try to access a layer from GeoServer and display on openlayers by the example here:
https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html

Here is the code I'm trying to access:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WMS GetFeatureInfo (Tile Layer)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
    <script>
      var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'ADMINISTRATIE:pdf',
                             'STYLES':'TEREN',
                              tiled:true,
                              transparent: true },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
      });

      var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: wmsSource
      });

      var view = new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [wmsLayer],
        target: 'map',
        view: view
      });

      map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
        var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
            {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
        if (url) {
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
              '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
        }
      });

      map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        var hit = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(pixel, function() {
          return true;
        });
        map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the error I encounter is the following:

```
Access to image at 'http: // localhost: 10000 / geoserver / ADMINISTRATIE / wms? SERVICE = WMS & VERSION = 1.3.0 & REQUEST = GetMap & FORMAT = image% 2Fpng & TRANSPARENT = true & LAYERS = ADMINISTRATIE% 3Apdf & STYLES = TEREN & tiled6 W & S = = transparent & true % 3A3857 & BBOX = -20037508.342789244% 2C0% 2C0% 2C20037508.342789244 'from origin' http: // localhost 'has been blocked by CORS policy: No' Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'header is present on the requested resource.
10000 / geoserver / ADMINISTRATION / WMS? SERVICE = WMS & VERSION = 1.3.0 & REQUEST = GetMap & FORMAT = image% 2Fpng & TRANSPARENT = true & LAYERS = ADMINISTRATION% 3Apdf & STYLES = LAND & tiled = true & Transparent = true & width = 256 & height = 256 & CRS = EPSG% 3A3857 & BBOX = -20,037,508.342789244% 2C0% 2C0% 2C20037508.342789244: 1 GET http: // localhost: 10000 / geoserver / ADMINISTRATIE / wms? SERVICE = WMS & VERSION = 1.3.0 & REQUEST = GetMap & FORMAT = image% 2Fpng & TRANSPARENT = true & LAYERS = ADMINISTRATIE% 3Apdf & STYLES & true & TY & true & tY 25 EPSG% 3A3857 & BBOX = -20037508.342789244% 2C0% 2C0% 2C20037508.342789244 net :: ERR_FAILED
Image (async)
nx @ ol.js: 719
k.load @ ol.js: 646
jg @ ol.js: 124
k.fl @ ol.js: 387
setTimeout (async)
k.Zo @ ol.js: 392
(anonymous) @ ol.js: 378
requestAnimationFrame (async)
k.render @ ol.js: 389
k.Tk @ ol.js: 389
b @ ol.js: 15
Na.b @ ol.js: 18
Va @ ol.js: 20
k.set @ ol.js: 20
k.I @ ol.js: 21
I @ ol.js: 380
(anonymous) @ test.php: 33
test.php: 1 Access to image at 'http: // localhost: 10000 / geoserver / ADMINISTRATIE / wms? SERVICE = WMS & VERSION = 1.3.0 & REQUEST = GetMap & FORMAT = image% 2Fpng & TRANSPARENT = true & LAYERS = ADMINISTRATIE% 3Apdf & STYLES = true & true 256 & HEIGHT = 256 & CRS = EPSG% 3A3857 & BBOX = 0% 2C0% 2C20037508.342789244% 2C20037508.342789244 'from origin' http: // localhost 'has been blocked by CORS policy: No' Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Do you have GeoServer running at port 10000 on your local machine and does it have that data?

Comment: Yes, because the web server runs on port 80 and that's why I put it on 10,000 geoservers.

Comment: You are being blocked by CORS

Comment: Oke how to deblock CORS?